# AJAX response returns malformed

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Trying to run this from the browser or as shown here with curl

I get a response of �zرy��a�a�a�a�a�a�a�a�aBEE�

It's an ubuntu 10.04 server running apache2
The data that is suppose to come back should be a JSON string `{ result: "true" }` or something of that sort so I don't think it's something wrong with the charset/encoding in the database.

```
> GET /ajax.php?f=setCurrency HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8k zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.15
> Host: 
> Accept: */*
> X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 06 Jun 2013 15:07:35 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.19
< Content-Encoding: none
< Content-Length: 30
< Content-Type: text/html
<
* Connection #0 to host www.tellavista.com left intact
* Closing connection #0

�zرy��a�a�a�a�a�a�a�a�aBEE�

[1]+  Done
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with your web application, not with your server setup.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the problem was that when you wrap in PHP 5.3 `json_encode(true)` and expect a json response it sometimes return a malformed response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add «Accept-Encoding:» to your request headers to ensure that you arent getting compressed data in return.

The «Content-Encoding» header do look OK, but one never knows what silly web servers might do.